# How to set Label Text property based on data selection from DropDownlist using Javascript in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am having two Label controls and a dropdownlist on my web form. I am displaying current date in Label1 and I want to display Expiry Date in Label2 based on selection of dropdownlist. What I am trying to do is I want to display expiry date within Label2 on selecting data from dropdownlist i.e. if "Upto 7 Days" then 7Days will be added to current date and the new date will be displayed within Label2.

My aspx page-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#ddlvalid").change(function () {
        var selectvalid = $("#ddlvalid option:selected").text();
        if (selectvalid == "Select Validity") {
            alert("Please Select Validity");
        }
        else if (selectvalid == "Upto 7 Days") {
            var d = new Date();
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = d.getDate();
            var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
            var valdate = 7;
            var expdate = d.setDate(day + valdate);
            document.getElementById('lblenddt').innerHTML = expdate;
        }
        else if (selectvalid == "Upto 15 Days") {
            var d = new Date();
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = d.getDate();
            var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
            var valdate = 15;
            var expdate = d.setDate(day + valdate);
            document.getElementById('lblenddt').innerHTML = expdate;
        }
        else if (selectvalid == "Upto 30 Days") {
            var d = new Date();
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = d.getDate();
            var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
            var valdate = 30;
            var expdate = d.setDate(day + valdate);
            document.getElementById('lblenddt').innerHTML = expdate;
        }
    });
window.onload = function show() {
        var d = new Date();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = d.getDate();
        var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
        document.getElementById('lblenqmdon').innerHTML = output;
    };
</script>
<body>
<div>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>Enquiry Made On:</td>
    <td>
        <label id="lblenqmdon" runat="server"></label>
    </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Enquiry Validity:</td>
    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlvalid" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem>Select Validity</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Upto 7 Days</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Upto 15 Days</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Upto 30 Days</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Enquiry Valid Upto:</td>
    <td>
        <label id="lblenddt" runat="server"></label>
    </td>
    </tr></table>
</div></body>
</html>
```

My Javascript code is not working. Please guide me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check what error are you receiving in your javascript ?

Comment: where is your <head> tag closed?

Comment: Why don't you use the value property of the DDL, e.g. 7 for "Upto 7 Days" - then just take the value of the selected item and add it.

Comment: And instead of using the older JS designation use the jQuery - $("#lbldnddt").text(expdate);

Comment: @Max There is no error in fact nothing is displayed with in label "lblenddt"

Comment: @Reena I missed to copy and paste <head> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function findDate() {

        var selectvalid = document.getElementById("<%=ddlvalid.ClientID  %>").value;

        if (selectvalid == "Select Validity") {
            alert("Please Select Validity");
        }
        else if (selectvalid == "Upto 7 Days") {

            var str = document.getElementById("<%=lblenqmdon.ClientID  %>").innerHTML;
            var parts = str.split('/');

            var month = parts[0] && parseInt(parts[0], 10);
            var day = parts[1] && parseInt(parts[1], 10);
            var year = parts[2] && parseInt(parts[2], 10);

            var duration = 7;

            if (day <= 31 && day >= 1 && month <= 12 && month >= 1) {
                var expiryDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
                expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + duration);

                var day = ('0' + expiryDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
                var month = ('0' + (expiryDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                var year = expiryDate.getFullYear();
                document.getElementById("<%=lblenddt.ClientID  %>").innerHTML = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

            }
        }
        else if (selectvalid == "Upto 15 Days") {

            var str = document.getElementById("<%=lblenqmdon.ClientID  %>").innerHTML;
            var parts = str.split('/');

            var month = parts[0] && parseInt(parts[0], 10);
            var day = parts[1] && parseInt(parts[1], 10);
            var year = parts[2] && parseInt(parts[2], 10);

            var duration = 15;

            if (day <= 31 && day >= 1 && month <= 12 && month >= 1) {
                var expiryDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
                expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + duration);

                var day = ('0' + expiryDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
                var month = ('0' + (expiryDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                var year = expiryDate.getFullYear();
                document.getElementById("<%=lblenddt.ClientID  %>").innerHTML = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

            }

        }
        else if (selectvalid == "Upto 30 Days") {

            var str = document.getElementById("<%=lblenqmdon.ClientID  %>").innerHTML;
            var parts = str.split('/');

            var month = parts[0] && parseInt(parts[0], 10);
            var day = parts[1] && parseInt(parts[1], 10);
            var year = parts[2] && parseInt(parts[2], 10);

            var duration = 30;

            if (day <= 31 && day >= 1 && month <= 12 && month >= 1) {
                var expiryDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
                expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + duration);

                var day = ('0' + expiryDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
                var month = ('0' + (expiryDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                var year = expiryDate.getFullYear();
                document.getElementById("<%=lblenddt.ClientID  %>").innerHTML = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

            }
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        getDate();
    };

    function getDate() {
        var dt = new Date();
        var day = dt.getDate();
        var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = dt.getFullYear();
        document.getElementById("<%=lblenqmdon.ClientID  %>").innerHTML = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    }
</script>
```

AND in Form

```
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlvalid" runat="server" onchange="javascript:findDate();">
                    <asp:ListItem>Select Validity</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Upto 7 Days</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Upto 15 Days</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Upto 30 Days</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hiral. Though I managed to do the same in a different way. .But still your way is also correct. Thanks again for your support :-)
Cheers. .

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do the same like this-$(function () {

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
$("#ddlvalid").change(function () {
            var selectvalid = $("#ddlvalid option:selected").text();
            if (selectvalid == "Select Validity") {
                alert("Please Select Validity");
            }
            else if (selectvalid == "Upto 7 Days") {

                var today = new Date();
                var tomorrow = new Date(today);
                tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 7);

                var dd = tomorrow.getDate();
                var mm = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1;
                var y = tomorrow.getFullYear();

                var output = tomorrow.getFullYear() + '/' + (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm + '/' + (dd < 10 ? '0' : '') + dd;
                document.getElementById('lblenddt').innerHTML = output;
            }
            else if (selectvalid == "Upto 15 Days") {
                var today = new Date();
                var tomorrow = new Date(today);
                tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 15);


                var dd = tomorrow.getDate();
                var mm = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1;
                var y = tomorrow.getFullYear();

                var output = tomorrow.getFullYear() + '/' + (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm + '/' + (dd < 10 ? '0' : '') + dd;
                document.getElementById('lblenddt').innerHTML = output;
            }
            else if (selectvalid == "Upto 30 Days") {
                var today = new Date();
                var tomorrow = new Date(today);
                tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 30);

                var dd = tomorrow.getDate();
                var mm = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1;
                var y = tomorrow.getFullYear();

                var output = tomorrow.getFullYear() + '/' + (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm + '/' + (dd < 10 ? '0' : '') + dd;
                document.getElementById('lblenddt').innerHTML = output;
            }
        });

        window.onload = function show() {
            var d = new Date();
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = d.getDate();
            var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
            document.getElementById('lblenqmdon').innerHTML = output;
        };
    });
    </script>
```